# Find $P(A^C\cap B)$

Tags: probability

Let $P(A)=0.4, P(B)=0.7, P(A\cup B)=0.9$.

I want to determine $P(A^C\cap B)$.

**My attempt:**

I know that $P(A^C)=1-P(A)$ and the inclusion-exclusion principle: $P(A\cap B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cup B)$, but it's not obvious to me how to proceed.

Comment: Just draw Venn diagram!!

Comment: @MatthewDaly I made a cap instead of a cup. Updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guide:

First, use

\begin{align}
P(A \cap B) = P(A)+P(B)-P(A \cup B)
\end{align}

then, you can compute $$P(A^C \cap B)=P(B)-P(A \cap B)$$

Answer (score 2):

Use the fact that $A^C\cap B$ is the same as the part of $B$ not in $A$, and draw a Venn diagram.

Answer (score 0):

$P\left(B\cap A\right)=P\left(A\right)+P\left(B\right)-P\left(B\cup A\right)=0.4+0.7-0.9=0.2\\P\left(B\right)=P\left(B\cap A\right)+P\left(B\cap A^C\right)\rightarrow 0.7=0.2+P\left(B\cap A^C\right)\rightarrow P\left(B\cap A^C\right)=\boxed{0.5}$

Answer (score 0):

$$P(A^c\cap B )= P(B) - P(A\cap B )  = 0.7 -
 0.2 = 0.5 $$